# Small Chip IC identification request - top code 9N (or N6) in 3 x 3 pad package

Tags: identification

Please help me identify this chip! It is square and 3mm in length, composed of 2 layer white ceramic. It has 9 golden pads. I think it's either a Hittite Microwave Corporation product or an Analog Devices product, but I was unable to pinpoint it.

[image: Front]

[image: Back]

Comment: Since Analog Devices has bought Hittite, not much info going on there.

Comment: I removed the "digital logic" tag, since you weren't mentioning digital logic in your question.

Comment: @Grosan - Hi, FYI these are the current "[Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710)". The more information you can supply from that list, the better the chances of identification. Please edit your question to add any additional information; don't write it as a comment (or as an answer). Also see the [tour] and [help] for more information about Stack Exchange sites, their rules, and the differences between them and typical internet forums. Thanks!

Comment: All right. Thank You all.

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be an "[NBB-312](https://www.qorvo.com/products/d/da000104) Cascadable Broadband GaAs MMIC Amplifier DC to 12GHz" made by RFMD (recently acquired by qorvo). Nice looking part, about $10 in 100's.

[image]

Goodness knows what led them to mark it with reversible characters, no underline, and pin 1 in the upper right. Maybe that's an MMIC thing. Also note, it's not a BGA (no balls at all).

Comment: PGA or LGA? looks more like a land grid

Comment: @JonRB You're right, of course. No pins either. Wonder why they call the package a MPGA.

Comment: Thank you very much! This must be it. Thanks for Your time and for looking into it. BR

Comment: @GrosanSergiu You can (and should) accept the answer if it is the best one and answers your question.